# Node webkit hotkey example not working

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, hotkeys

I'm trying to play around with node webkits hotkey example which can be viewed on their Shortcut's page here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Shortcut

Here's my code:

test.js

```
// Load native UI library.
var gui = window.require('nw.gui');

var option = {
  key : "Ctrl+Shift+A",
  active : function() {
    console.log("Global desktop keyboard shortcut: " + this.key + " active."); 
  },
  failed : function(msg) {
    // :(, fail to register the |key| or couldn't parse the |key|.
    console.log(msg);
  }
};

// Create a shortcut with |option|.
var shortcut = new gui.Shortcut(option);

// Register global desktop shortcut, which can work without focus.
gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(shortcut);

// If register |shortcut| successfully and user struck "Ctrl+Shift+A", |shortcut|
// will get an "active" event.

// You can also add listener to shortcut's active and failed event.
shortcut.on('active', function() {
  console.log("Global desktop keyboard shortcut: " + this.key + " active."); 
});

shortcut.on('failed', function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});

// Unregister the global desktop shortcut.
gui.App.unregisterGlobalHotKey(shortcut);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script>
        require("./test.js");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node.js <script>document.write(process.version)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "main": "index.html",
    "dependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw"
  }
}
```

It breaks at this line on test.js saying undefined is not a function.

```
var shortcut = new gui.Shortcut(option);
```

Comment: The example on the site does seem to be broken at the moment (at least in OS X). See this https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3263

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue that I created on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
gui.App.unregisterGlobalHotKey(shortcut);
```

In your code you register it, then delete. It working well for me (mac, nwjs 0.12)

Comment: I already tried that, it did not work. It breaks before it gets to that line anyway.

Comment: Undefined is not a function.

Comment: On what line? Try `<script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>` in your html

Comment: As my original post says, it breaks on this line ```var shortcut = new gui.Shortcut(option);```

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: I run my application by building it the way the tutorial says to. By running ```nw .``` inside the directory where my ```package.json``` file is.

Answer (score 0):

As shaynem in (https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3263#issuecomment-89679115) points out you should be running at least node-webkit >= 0.10.0

You should make sure your PATH (or the build tool you're using, e.g. nodebob) is not referencing any old leftover versions of node-webkit after you upgrade.

Also if you're on Ubuntu, you might stumble upon an open issue (https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3199)

Answer (score 0):

note webkit 0.13.0 has a bug where the the k is lowercase even though the method is documented with an uppercase K. Try:

```
registerGlobalHotkey(shortcut);
```

to verify this bug exists do:

```
var util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(nw.App));
```